# Check if two conditions are both true, only one is true or none is true in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have two conditions C1 and C2. I want my program to perform something different in case that C1 and C2 are true, C1 is true but not C2, C2 is true but not C1, neither C1 nor C2 is true.

Now I have this code:

```
if C1 and C2:
    ...
elif C1:
    ...
elif C2:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Is there a more efficient way to code this in Python?

Comment: Define "more efficient": less lines of codes? faster? If the code in the place of the ellipses is different each time, this may be the clearest way of doing things. If there are repeated code parts, it'll depend on the structure if things can be more efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just slightly.

```
if C1:
    if C2: 
        # both true
    else:
        # only C1 true
elif C2:
    # only C2 true
else:
    # both false
```

This way, both C1 and C2 are checked exactly once each. The question is, are you more interested in efficiency or readability.